# Angular 11:- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms'

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the form in angular 11 but getting below error-
Error: ./src/app/components/register/register.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms' in 'C:\Users\Ram Chaurasiya\Desktop\Projects\MyRealtimeProjects\onlineLearningPortal\src\app\components\register'

Comment: Try npm install @angular/forms --save

Comment: I tried npm install @angular/forms --save also but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please check your imports in register.component.ts
It should be from "@angular/forms" only

Comment: in register.component.ts I imported forms only --> import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; but i don't understand why it is looking for ../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms/forms